# How to rename DataGridView Header by double click

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I am having a datagridview. In that suppose I give the header name as wrong, suppose say, instead of "test", i gave it as "tst". So i need to rename in this case. So what i expect is I need to double click that header and rename it. But in code I can't directly give it as "test", since it can be whatever. By double clicking i need to change in that display itself. I can able to catch the double click event. It is as below. Please suggest me a code which makes me to edit and rename the header.

```
private void dgvParametersEdit_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
column.HeaderText = String.Concat("Column ",column.Index.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but this code doesnt work.. i couldn't able to edit.. when i double click it, nothing is happening..